# FixedStack of the Container hierarchy in Java

Tags: java, reinventing-the-wheel, stack, collections

## Introduction/Disclaimer

This is a project for educational purposes. I'm not intending to replace the *"award-winning"* [Collections Framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/overview.html) in `java.util`. I'm just looking for constructive criticism. For obvious reasons, I'm tagging it as [reinventing-the-wheel](/questions/tagged/reinventing-the-wheel).

I'd like to see someone break my code. Preferably in a multi-threaded environment. (My code is *not* thread-safe)

## Overview

The `Container` class defines the minimal skeletal structure for all Data Structures that I implement. Depending on the requirement, I'm providing two implementations: *Fixed* capacity implementations and implementations using *Linked Lists*. For this question, I'm limiting the discussion to `FixedStack` and all the related classes.

### `Container.java`

```
package astrobleme.core.datastructures;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.StringJoiner;

/**
 * This is the root of the Container hierarchy. This contains methods
 * that provide a common skeletal structure to all implementations. The
 * modifying methods will have different names, depending on the type of
 * data structure it is.
 *
 * @author Subhomoy Haldar
 * @version 2017.02.15
 */
public abstract class Container<E> {
    /**
     * Returns the number of elements currently in the Container. It is
     * guaranteed to be a non-negative number.
     * <p>
     * <b>NOTE:</b> If the number of elements exceeds
     * {@link Long#MAX_VALUE Long#MAX_VALUE}, then it will return
     * {@code Long#MAX_VALUE}.
     *
     * @return The number of elements in this Container.
     */
    abstract long size();

    /**
     * Returns {@code true} if the number of elements in this Container is
     * within the allowed maximum size for arrays, and hopefully, it might
     * be able to create an array out of it.
     * <p>
     * However, it depends on the amount of memory allocated by the VM and
     * even smaller sizes may cause a {@link OutOfMemoryError}. It is advised
     * to re-start the VM with different arguments to allow for allocation
     * of more memory if needed. It is encouraged to compactify the element type
     * instead, to reduce overhead.
     *
     * @return {@code false} if it is absolutely impossible to represent it
     * as an array.
     */
    boolean willProbablyFitArray() {
        // The value allowed by most VMs:
        final long MAX = Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8;
        return size() <= MAX;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the elements of this Container in an array, if possible.
     * <p>
     * If it cannot fit the data into an array, and assuming no
     * {@link OutOfMemoryError} is thrown, this method will return {@code null}.
     *
     * @return The elements of this Container in an array, if possible.
     */
    public abstract Object[] toArray();

    /**
     * Returns the elements of the Container in the given array, if it
     * can accommodate, or a new array of the same type.
     * <p>
     * If it cannot fit the data into an array, and assuming no
     * {@link OutOfMemoryError} is thrown, this method will return {@code null}.
     *
     * @param array The array in which to store the elements if possible,
     *              or in a new array of the same type.
     * @param <T>   The type of the array needed.
     * @return The elements of the Container in the given array, if it
     * can accommodate, or a new array of the same type.
     * @throws ClassCastException If the elements cannot be converted to
     *                            the given type.
     */
    public abstract <T extends E> T[] toArray(T[] array) throws ClassCastException;

    /**
     * Returns {@code true} if this Container has no elements.
     *
     * @return {@code true} if this Container has no elements.
     */
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size() == 0;
    }

    /**
     * Removes all of its elements.
     */
    public abstract void clear();

    /**
     * Returns the String representation of this Container. If it has elements
     * within the specified limit, then it tries to return a String with a
     * description of all the elements inside it. If it has too many elements,
     * then it just returns the class name followed by the number of elements.
     *
     * @return The String representation of this Container.
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // The String representation will be stored in a char array ultimately.
        // So, it'd be better if was representable as an array.
        // Otherwise, don't bother. Just return the class name and size.
        if (!willProbablyFitArray()) {
            return this.getClass().getName() + " : " + size();
        }
        Object[] array = toArray();
        StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(", ", "[", "]");
        for (Object element : array) {
            joiner.add(element == this ? "(this container)" : element.toString());
        }
        return joiner.toString();
    }

    /**
     * A simple implementation of the {@link Object#equals(Object)} method  that
     * relies on the {@link #toArray()} method. If there is a possibility that
     * the number of elements might exceed the specified array limit, then it is
     * advised to override this method and provide a custom logic.
     *
     * @param object The object to check against.
     * @return {@code true} if the given object is a Container and has the same
     * elements in the order specified by their definition (which may imply no
     * order).
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (!(object instanceof Container)) {
            return false;
        }
        Container container = (Container) object;
        return size() == container.size()
                && Arrays.equals(toArray(), container.toArray());
    }
}
```

### `Stack.java`

```
package astrobleme.core.datastructures;


import astrobleme.core.datastructures.exceptions.OverflowException;
import astrobleme.core.datastructures.exceptions.UnderflowException;

/**
 * Defines the basic structure for all Stacks. A Stack is a data structure
 * that provides LIFO (last in first out) functionality. It achieves this
 * via two methods: {@link #push(Object)} and {@link #pop()}. The former
 * "pushes" an element onto the Stack, while the latter returns the last
 * added or "top-most" element of the Stack.
 * <p>
 * There is an additional method called {@link #peek()} that returns the
 * topmost element of the Stack without "popping" it off.
 *
 * @author Subhomoy Haldar
 * @version 2017.02.14
 */
public abstract class Stack<E> extends Container<E> {
    /**
     * Adds an element onto the Stack. This element (if successfully pushed
     * onto the Stack) will the one that will be returned by a subsequent
     * call to {@link #pop()}.
     *
     * @param element The element to push onto the Stack.
     * @throws OverflowException If the Stack tries to exceed its fixed capacity
     *                           or cannot accommodate too many elements.
     */
    public abstract void push(E element) throws OverflowException;

    /**
     * Returns the element that was most recently added to the Stack and
     * also removes it from the Stack. If the Stack is empty, that is no
     * element was added, it will throw an {@link UnderflowException}.
     *
     * @return The most recently added element.
     * @throws UnderflowException If the Stack is empty.
     */
    public abstract E pop() throws UnderflowException;

    /**
     * Returns the element that was most recently added to the Stack but
     * does not remove it. If the Stack is empty, it will not throw an
     * Exception. Instead, it returns {@code null}.
     *
     * @return The most recently added element.
     */
    public abstract E peek();

    /**
     * Creates an exact copy of the Stack, with the same initial parameters
     * (like capacity) and the same state of elements.
     *
     * @return An exact copy of this Stack.
     */
    public abstract Stack<E> copy();

    /**
     * Removes all of its elements.
     */
    @Override
    public void clear() {
        while (!isEmpty()) {
            pop();
        }
    }
}
```

### `FixedStack.java`

```
package astrobleme.core.datastructures;

import astrobleme.core.datastructures.exceptions.OverflowException;
import astrobleme.core.datastructures.exceptions.UnderflowException;

import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * An array-based implementation of a Stack that has a fixed capacity.
 * It is designed to be light-weight and fast.
 *
 * @author Subhomoy Haldar
 * @version 2017.02.15
 */
public class FixedStack<E> extends Stack<E> {
    private final Object[] a;
    private int top;

    /**
     * Creates a new Stack with the given capacity.
     *
     * @param capacity The required capacity.
     */
    public FixedStack(final int capacity) {
        a = new Object[capacity];
        top = -1;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of elements currently in the Stack. It is
     * guaranteed to be a non-negative number.
     * <p>
     *
     * @return The number of elements in this Stack.
     */
    @Override
    public long size() {
        return top + 1;
    }

    /**
     * Adds an element onto the Stack. This element (if successfully pushed
     * onto the Stack) will the one that will be returned by a subsequent
     * call to {@link #pop()}.
     *
     * @param element The element to push onto the Stack.
     * @throws OverflowException If the Stack tries to exceed its fixed capacity
     *                           or cannot accommodate too many elements.
     */
    @Override
    public void push(E element) throws OverflowException {
        if (top == a.length - 1) {
            throw new OverflowException(a.length);
        }
        a[++top] = element;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the element that was most recently added to the Stack and
     * also removes it from the Stack. If the Stack is empty, that is no
     * element was added, it will throw an {@link UnderflowException}.
     *
     * @return The most recently added element.
     * @throws UnderflowException If the Stack is empty.
     */
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public E pop() throws UnderflowException {
        if (top == -1) {
            throw new UnderflowException();
        }
        return (E) a[top--];
    }

    /**
     * Returns the element that was most recently added to the Stack but
     * does not remove it. If the Stack is empty, it will not throw an
     * Exception. Instead, it returns {@code null}.
     *
     * @return The most recently added element.
     */
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public E peek() {
        return top == -1 ? null : (E) a[top];
    }

    /**
     * Returns the elements of this Stack in an array. It creates an
     * independent "snapshot" of its contents when this method is invoked,
     * which is not affected when the Stack is modified later.
     *
     * @return The elements of this Container in an array.
     */
    @Override
    public Object[] toArray() {
        Object[] elements = Arrays.copyOf(a, top + 1);
        ArrayUtil.reverse(elements, 0, elements.length);
        return elements;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the snapshot of the elements of the Stack in the given array,
     * if it can accommodate, or a new array of the same type.
     * <p>
     * If it cannot fit the data into an array, and assuming no
     * {@link OutOfMemoryError} is thrown, this method will return {@code null}.
     *
     * @param array The array in which to store the elements if possible,
     *              or in a new array of the same type.
     * @return The elements of the Container in the given array, if it
     * can accommodate, or a new array of the same type.
     */
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T extends E> T[] toArray(T[] array) {
        T[] container;
        if (array.length > top) {
            container = array;
        } else {
            container = (T[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(
                    array.getClass().getComponentType(), top + 1
            );
        }
        for (int i = 0, j = top; i <= top; i++, j--) {
            container[j] = (T) a[i];
        }
        return container;
    }

    /**
     * Returns an exact copy of this FixedStack with the same capacity and
     * the same state of elements and top index.
     * <p>
     * If the elements are mutable, then the two Stacks might not be
     * completely independent. It is encouraged to keep the elements
     * immutable.
     *
     * @return An exact copy of this Fixed Stack.
     */
    @Override
    public Stack<E> copy() {
        FixedStack<E> copy = new FixedStack<E>(a.length);
        System.arraycopy(a, 0, copy.a, 0, a.length);
        copy.top = top;
        return copy;
    }
}
```

### `ArrayUtil.java`

Not much, but I plan to add more methods.

```
package astrobleme.core.datastructures;

/**
 * A utility class that performs operation on arrays.
 *
 * @author Subhomoy Haldar
 * @version 2017.02.15
 */
public class ArrayUtil {
    /**
     * Reverses the elements of the given array within the specified range.
     *
     * @param a    The array to change.
     * @param from The starting index (inclusive).
     * @param to   The ending index (exclusive).
     * @param <T>  The type of the array.
     */
    public static <T> void reverse(T[] a, int from, int to) {
        for (int i = from, j = to - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
            T temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

### `UnderflowException.java`

```
package astrobleme.core.datastructures.exceptions;

/**
 * This Exception is thrown when pop() is called on an empty Stack or dequeue()
 * or some similar removal operation is called on a Collection.
 *
 * @author Subhomoy Haldar
 * @version 2017.02.07
 */
public class UnderflowException extends RuntimeException {
    /**
     * Returns the message that is displayed when the Exception is thrown.
     *
     * @return The message that is displayed when the Exception is thrown.
     */
    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
        return "No more elements to remove from Container.";
    }
}
```

### `OverflowException.java`

```
package astrobleme.core.datastructures.exceptions;

/**
 * A custom Exception to define if the Stack or Queue or any other Container
 * has run out of space (which may happen in case of a FixedStack or if the number of
 * elements is too large, comparable to {@link Integer#MAX_VALUE}).
 *
 * @author Subhomoy Haldar
 * @version 2017.02.07
 */
public class OverflowException extends RuntimeException {
    private final int maxSize;

    /**
     * Creates a custom Exception with fixed size or -1 if it is expandable.
     *
     * @param size The capacity of the Stack or -1 to indicate an expandable
     *             Collection.
     */
    public OverflowException(final int size) {
        maxSize = size;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the message that is displayed when the Exception is thrown.
     *
     * @return The message that is displayed when the Exception is thrown.
     */
    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
        return maxSize != -1
                ? "Cannot store any more elements in Container of size : " + maxSize
                : "Too many elements, cannot accommodate.";
    }
}
```

## The Test

I am using TestNG for this purpose.

### `FixedStackTest.java`

```
package astrobleme.core.datastructures;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

import static org.testng.Assert.*;

/**
 * Mostly trivial test cases.
 *
 * @author Subhomoy Haldar
 * @version 2017.02.15
 */
public class FixedStackTest {

    private final int size = 10;
    private final int limit = size * 2;
    private final Random random = new Random();

    private FixedStack<Integer> stack;
    private Integer[] mirror;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        stack = new FixedStack<>(size);
        mirror = new Integer[size];
        for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            int randomInt = random.nextInt(limit);
            mirror[i] = randomInt;
            stack.push(randomInt);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testSize() throws Exception {
        assertEquals(size, stack.size());
    }

    @Test
    public void testPush() throws Exception {
        int[] store = new int[size];
        stack.clear();
        for (int i = 0, j = size - 1; i < size; i++, j--) {
            int randomInt = random.nextInt(limit);
            stack.push(randomInt);
            store[j] = randomInt;
            assertEquals(randomInt, stack.peek().intValue());
            assertEquals(i + 1, stack.size());
        }
        for (int element : store) {
            assertEquals(element, stack.pop().intValue());
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testToArray() throws Exception {
        Object[] array = new Object[size];
        System.arraycopy(mirror, 0, array, 0, size);
        assertEquals(array, stack.toArray());
        assertEquals(mirror, stack.toArray(new Integer[size]));
    }

    @Test
    public void testCopy() throws Exception {
        Stack<Integer> copy = stack.copy();
        assertEquals(copy, stack);
        assertEquals(copy.toArray(new Integer[size]), mirror);
    }

    @Test
    public void testWillProbablyFitArray() throws Exception {
        assertTrue(stack.willProbablyFitArray());
    }

    @Test
    public void testToString() throws Exception {
        assertEquals(Arrays.toString(mirror), stack.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

2 crashing use cases:

```
new FixedStack(-1);
new FixedStack(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

Performance: clearing could be much faster when implemented in `FixedStack`:

```
@Override
public void clear() {
    top = -1;
}
```